# track application stack change event wp8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, application-lifecycle

I am new to WP8 development, I need to know is there a way to trace the application stack change (check if application comes from deactive (dormant) to active (tombstoned) state) event in wp8.1 same as android gives us. If it is how we can trace that particular event and before opening the app change stack with my own app. Actually I am planing to create an applock application same as android have.

Thanks and Regards

Inderjeet Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to 'track' the state of your app - not the application stack. However it also depends on the platform you are targeting:

- for *WP8.0* and *WP8.1 Silverlight* - you have [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.activated(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Deactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated(v=vs.105).aspx) events. For more help - read [App activation and deactivation for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx) - there are more cases to be considered.
- for *WP8.1 WinRT* - you have [Suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx) and [Resuming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx) events - for more help read [Application lifecycle (Windows Runtime apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx) - there are also more cases to be considered here.

I doubt you will be able to exchange the opened app.

Comment: hey @Romasz, thanks for your quick response. actually i need an event to trace which app on top of the stack or which app is currently active. I need it in outside environment of the app not inside the environment of the app. Actually i am trying to create an applock application same as android have.

Comment: @InderjeetSinghSethi AFAIK With official API it's not possible.

Comment: humm, as expected :), there is something unofficial??

Comment: @InderjeetSinghSethi I don't know.